# Specify the driver used to read in a file for gdal.Warp in python osgeo

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo

In base gdal, it is possible to specify the input format driver using `-if`. How can this be set when calling [osgeo.gdal.Warp](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.Warp)?

Comment: I would try gdal.openEx https://gdal.org/api/raster_c_api.html#_CPPv410GDALOpenExPKcjPPCKcPPCKcPPCKc with "AllowedDrivers".

Comment: Alternative solution is to deny the use of some unwanted driver(s) by setting the GDAL_SKIP configuration option https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html#driver-management.

Comment: Thanks, I will try gdal.openEx using AllowedDrivers. To further clarify the question, I have a set of files in a known format, but with a random file extension. GDAL just gives up because it doesn't recognize the extension, so I'd like to force it try the correct format (netCDF). It looks like this should work.